# cannot configure log4j behaviour while coding in Anypoint studio 7

Tags: log4j, mule, anypoint-studio

I am having difficulty trying to configure console log behaviour in Anypoint studio.

I have tried configuring the PatternLayout in all the log files I can find

1. log4j2.xml in main resources
2. log4j2-test.xml in test resources
3. log4j2.xml in mule_home <== this get overwritten everytime I restart Anypointstudio
4. log4j2.properties, this file has line `log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout`

**but none of them takes effect**

I am not sure which precedents which

default PatternLayout `<PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n"/>`

this produces long and lengthy logs such as `INFO  2019-09-19 16:00:03,520 [[MuleRuntime].cpuLight.10: [b2b-fabric-supplier-po-generate-api].supplier_LookupSupplierGroup_Flow.CPU_LITE @45e00f0d] [event: 7c7e6490-dab3-11e9-aabc-6c4b9035d35b] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: enqueuePOResult before add: []` which causes great trouble reading

basically I only have to read what is after the %t thread, the %m%n message

Would want to know what I need to do to do this configuration

**Edit: I am not having problem with the patternlayout syntax, I am having problem that whereever I edit the patternlayout, it takes no effect.**

I don't think many programmers want to work with log displayed as such
[image: log messages too long]

Answer (score 0):

Log4j Conversion patterns for thread
For debugging multi-threaded applications, log4j provides the following conversion characters:

- %t: thread name
- %x: thread’s nested diagnostic context.
- %X: thread’s mapped diagnostic context.

Pattern: `[%p] %d [%t] %x %c %M - %m%n`

Example output:
[INFO] 2012-11-02 23:28:26,178 [main] MyClass foo - this is a log message

For more info please use this info
 [https://www.codejava.net/coding/common-conversion-patterns-for-log4js-patternlayout](http://%20https://www.codejava.net/coding/common-conversion-patterns-for-log4js-patternlayout)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you remove this information from the pattern, what you gain in smaller log lines, you lose it later in troubleshooting when you'll have any issues. This information could be invaluable at that time. For this I don't recommend to remove it, though I agree that it makes reading the logs more cumbersome in Studio.

Let's clarify what is each file for:

1. log4j2.xml in main resources: this is the log file for your application. None of the others will work. **You need to restart the application after modifying it**. This is the same for any files except for Mule XML configuration files.
2. log4j2-test.xml in test resources: this is the log4j2.xml file used for MUnit tests, in case that you need something different for testing.
3. log4j2.xml in mule_home: This is for the Mule Runtime. It affects the mule_ee.log output. You don't need to change this in Studio.
4. log4j.properties (note that this is for log4j v1, not log4j2): I guess it is for backwards compatibility of some component that relies on log4j v1.

Comment: as I mentioned in the question, editing all 4 files, and restarting my app, makes no effect on the logging messages, that is the main issue I am trying to resolve.I can always add them back once I have completed development

Comment: I tested in Studio and it seems you are right with respect to the pattern. Probably Studio injects its own appender to be able to show the logs into the console.The logs in the filesystem respect the actual pattern in the RollingFile appender in my app log4j2.xml file. Only the console tab keep the same pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the file system log then.

Comment: In Studio 7 the logs in the file system are in the Studio installation, where the tooling plugin is installed for the embedded Mule version, in the mule/logs subdirectory.